# How to write a for loop to parse three different varibles in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, survival-analysis

I have difficulty to write a for loop to parse three different cols for further plotting.

For example,

I have table with 3 different cols/variables, each variable has 4 different types

```
 colnames    cells         genes       treatment    survival days
    1         a            a2           a3
    2         b            b2           b3
    3         c            c2           c3
    4         d            d2           d3
```

and finally, I want to plot survival curve, like:

```
ggsurvplot(survival days, status)~ cells+genes+treatment, data)
```

How can I use for loops to make sure I can plot all combinations:

```
1. cells a + gene a2+ treatment a3
2. cells a + gene b2 + treatment a3 
etc.al
```

It should have 64 combinations, so a lot of plots.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it all 3 column combinations?

Comment: yes, it is just for example, my real data is 90 rows, but still 3 cols.  So I need to run each combination with these three cols to plot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cells<-c("a","b","c","d")
genes<-c("a2","b2","c2","d2")
treatment<-c("a3","b3","c3","d3")
mydf<-data.frame(cells=cells,genes=genes,treatment=treatment)
expand.grid(mydf)
```

Expected output

```
> tail(expand.grid(mydf))
   cells genes treatment
59     c    c2        d3
60     d    c2        d3
61     a    d2        d3
62     b    d2        d3
63     c    d2        d3
64     d    d2        d3
```

If you need to deal with duplicates:

```
cells<-c("a","b","b","b")
genes<-c("a2","a2","a2","b2")
treatment<-c("a3","c3","c3","c3")
mydf<-data.frame(cells=cells,genes=genes,treatment=treatment)
expand.grid(unique(mydf$cells),unique(mydf$genes),unique(mydf$treatment))
```

Result:

```
  Var1 Var2 Var3
1    a   a2   a3
2    b   a2   a3
3    a   b2   a3
4    b   b2   a3
5    a   a2   c3
6    b   a2   c3
7    a   b2   c3
8    b   b2   c3
```

Comment: How do I modify this, if my actual data values are duplicate. For example, I have 90 rows for cells, but only 4 unique cell types.

Comment: I modified the answer